# creating groupby function from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have mock dataframe consist of these 2 columns (characters and values), I want create a function which iterate the column "characters" based on its unique value then fetch all the values associate with it. Kindly advice.

Expected result:

```
temp = ({a:[100,400], b:[200,200], c:[200,200]})
```

```
df
characters values
  a         100
  b         200
  a         400
  b         200
  c         200
  c         200
```

I know I have to create an empty list then iterate of the column "characters" and append the values in the list. Here is my rough idea (not complete)

```
def groups_per_character(df):
    temp = {}
    for characters,values in df.values():
        for character in characters:
            if character not in temp:
                temp[character]=[]
            temp[character].append(values)
        return temp
```

So basically im trying to do a function than similar but no same as below

```
df.groupby("characters").min()
```

error occur when running the function
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a separate function.

Just use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`df.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
In [1687]: x = df.groupby('characters').agg(list).to_dict()

In [1688]: temp = x['values']

In [1689]: temp
Out[1689]: {'a': [100, 400], 'b': [200, 200], 'c': [200, 200]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is just an iteration, with no calculations, you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(df.characters, df["values"]):
    d[k].append(v)

d
defaultdict(list, {'a': [100, 400], 'b': [200, 200], 'c': [200, 200]})
```